# Can't send mail with php mail() angular

Tags: php, angular, sendmail

After many search, my problem is still here. 
I'm new with angular and i try to send a mail in my personnal adresse after validate a contact form.

I have no mail after submit but if i copy and past the file mail.php in my server and i ping in i have a mail with default values.

When i use postman aplication a have the return of echo in my mail.php

I need your help

Here my contact.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup , FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Http }    from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styles:['input.ng-invalid {border-left: 5px solid red;}',
    'input.ng-valid {border-left:5px solid green;}',
    'input.ng-pristine {border-left: 1px solid grey;}',
    'textarea.ng-invalid {border-left: 5px solid red;}',
      'textarea.ng-valid {border-left:5px solid green;}',
      'textarea.ng-pristine {border-left: 1px solid grey;}']
  // styleUrls: ['../../app.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    name: string;
    email: string;
    message: string;
    endpoint : string;

    http : Http;

    constructor(http : Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    userForm = new FormGroup({
        nom: new FormControl(null),
        prenom: new FormControl(null),
        email: new FormControl(null),
        telephone: new FormControl(null),
        message: new FormControl(null)
    });

    onSubmit(){
        console.log(this.userForm.value);
        let postVars = {
          email : this.email,
          name : this.name,
          message : this.message
        };
            this.endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/src/app/page/contact/mail.php";
        this.http.post(this.endpoint, postVars)
        .subscribe(
            response => console.log(response),
            response => console.log(response)
        )
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    //This data could really come from some inputs on the interface - but let's keep it simple.
    this.email = "mypersonaladress@gmail.com";
    this.name = "Hayden Pierce";
    this.message = "Hello, this is Hayden.";

        //Start php via the built in server: $ php -S localhost:8000
            this.endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/src/app/page/contact/mail.php";
    }


}
```

here my contact.component.html

```
<main>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="col-xs-12 text-center">Vous desirez discuter un moment?</p>
            <p class="col-xs-12 text-center">Vous etes sur au bon endroit ?</p>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="userForm" method="POST" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Nom</label>
                <input type="text" name="nom" #refNom class="form-control" formControlName="nom">
                <b>{{refNom.className}}</b>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="userForm.controls['nom'].hasError('required') && ( userForm.controls['nom'].touched)">
                    Merci de rentrer un nom
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="userForm.controls['nom'].hasError('minlength')">
                    Il faut écrire un nom avec plus de deux characteres
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="userForm.controls['nom'].hasError('maxlength')">
                    Vous n'avez pas un diminutif?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Prenom</label>
                <input type="text" #refPrenom class="form-control" formControlName="prenom">
                <b>{{refPrenom.className}}</b>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="userForm.controls['prenom'].hasError('required') && ( userForm.controls['prenom'].touched)">
                    Merci de rentrer un prénom
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="userForm.controls['prenom'].hasError('minlength')">
                    Il faut écrire un prénom avec plus de deux characteres
                </div>
                <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="userForm.controls['prenom'].hasError('maxlength')">
                    Vous n'avez pas un diminutif?
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>email</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" formControlName="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telephone">Telephone</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="telephone">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Votre message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" formControlName="message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" [disabled]="!userForm.valid" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</main>
```

here my mail.php file

```
    <?php
$recipient = 'mypersonaladress@gmail.com\n';
$subject = 'new message\n';
$headers = "From: \n";
$message = '$params->message\n';
mail('mypersonaladress@gmail.com', 'mon sujet', 'coucou');

switch($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']){
    case("OPTIONS"): //Allow preflighting to take place.
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type");
        exit;
    case("POST"): //Send the email;
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

        $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
        $params = json_decode($json);
        $email = $params->email;
        $name = $params->name;
        $message = '$params->message\n';

        $recipient = 'mypersonaladress@gmail.com\n';
        $subject = 'new message\n';
        $headers = "From: toto@toto.com\n";
        if(mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers)){
            echo'totooo';
        }
    //    mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers);
        break;
    default: //Reject any non POST or OPTIONS requests.
        header("Allow: POST", true, 405);
        exit;
}
?>
```

i have no error on the bash for ng serve 
and on the bash php -S 
  localhost:8000 
  i can see 
  [Thu Apr 13 14:41:37 2017] 127.0.0.1:34118 [200]: 
  /src/app/page/contact/mail.php

i dont know how to fix this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending an email with AngularJS and PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31145934/sending-an-email-with-angularjs-and-php)

Comment: The problem is i have no email with simple quote value. i think angular dont go in my mail.php file when submit form and i dont know why

Comment: Or where i can put this code in mine ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and set the url parameter with `URLSearchParams` and use `RequestOptions` and set headers with `x-www-form-urlencoded`. I also noticed the weird use of `Http`, remove declaring http in component: `http : Http`;

and change your constructor to:

```
constructor(private http : Http) { }
```

But back to the POST request. Import the following:

```
import { RequestOptions, URLSearchParams, Headers } from '@angular/http';
```

Your `onSubmit`:

```
onSubmit(){
  let body = new URLSearchParams();
  body.set('email', this.email);
  body.set('name', this.name);
  body.set('message', this.message);

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  this.endpoint = "http://localhost:8000/src/app/page/contact/mail.php";

    this.http.post(this.endpoint, body, options)
      .subscribe(
        response => console.log(response)
    )
}
```

Hopefully this helps! Furthermore, I suggest you move all your http request to an actual service, that is usually the way to do it ;)

Comment: I have an error " cannot post/contact" in the page after submit my form. Thank for your interest in my problem.

Comment: Did you make the changes with removing `http:Http` and just having the http injected in the constructor?

Comment: Thank a lot it's work without error :)  you say i need to move all my http request to an actual service. What do you want say by that ? I'm new with dev ^^

Comment: You are welcome! Well you do not *have* to make a service, but this is usually how we do it. Handle all http requests in a service, and then just subscribe in the component. As per can be seen in the official docs, they are also using a separate service for http-requests: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Comment: Thank for advice. Now i need make in another page a database call and display the content. I will refactoring my code before ;)